# how to put this distorted data into the csv file, in the table format

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Please find below the code that I am using to put distorted data into CSV file in the table format:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

f = open('moneyControl-bonus','w' , newline = '')
writer = csv.writer(f)

f2 = open('moneyControl-dividend','w' , newline = '')
writer2 = csv.writer(f2)

url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/upcoming_actions/home.html'

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url,headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
div = soup.find_all('div',class_='tbldata36 PT10')[0]

for table in div.find_all('table'):
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
         writer.writerow[row]

    
div2 = soup.find_all('div',class_='tbldata36 PT20')[0]

for table2 in soup.find_all('table'):
     for row2 in table2.find_all('tr'):
            writer2.writerow[row2]
```

Comment: Can you properly indent your code?

Comment: Please add some more context, for example what the data looks like so that we can reproduce this as accurately as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pandas`? This the default library to be used in writing the csv format.

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
```

You can write into the CSV file by either passing list of lists or by dictonary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':['a','b','c','d']})
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d']],columns=['col1','col2'])

df.to_csv(path_and_name_of_file)
```

You can use many different formats with that one such as Excel, table, text, json etc.

Please take a look at the [official DataFrame Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)